Proof Checking for State Machines Similar to TLA+
I'm wanting to find a modern proof assistant that I can use for modeling distributed systems or similar protocols/algorithms.
TLA+ is the most commonly used language in that field, but I recently found Quint, which checks a lot of boxes for me, being more modern and easier to read, approach, and get setup.
One thing I'm not sure about with Quint is that it may not provide a mechanism for creating and checking inductive proofs.
I've done some rudimentary theorem proving with Coq, and later Lean. I really enjoyed Lean. I would love to be able to use something with the formal proof power of Lean, but then I think I might be missing out on some of the practical features of the more brute force model checkers like TLC or the Apalache model checker used by Quint.
The model checkers have the nice ability to find where some invariant doesn't hold and show you which steps to take to get to that point. I don't know that I'd be able to emulate anything similar in Lean, even if I would have a more enjoyable experience when it comes to actually writing the proof.
I'm relatively new to this space but I'm quite convinced that formal specification and model checking/proofs are not something that should be only usable/useful by very mathematics focused individuals or big businesses with a lot on the line.
I'm not sure if model checkers like Apalache are good enough, and maybe I should just use Quint and not worry about formal proofs?
I'm also wondering if it's possible to create a library or pattern for checking state machines in Lean that would be convenient enough to use, as long as I knew that I wanted to create an inductive proof eventually.
